# How to grab text after newline in a text file no clean of spaces, tabs

Tags: bash, grep, text-processing

Assume this: It needs to pass a file name as an argument.

This is the only text I’m showing. The remaining text has more data (not shown). The problem: The text is semi-clean, full of whitespace, tabs, Unicode, isn't clean and has to be like this (my needs), so copy/paste this exact text doesn't work (formatted by markup):

I have *some* text like this:

```
*** *
more text with spaces and  tabs
*****
1
Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop
    Usd324.32           2 Usd534.22
2
21st New tetx that will like to select with pattern, 334 pop
    Usd162.14

*** *
more text with spaces and tabs, unicode
*****
```

I'm trying to grab this explicit text:

- `1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop Usd324.32`

because of the `newline` and `whitespace`, the next command only grabs `1`:

```sh
grep -E '1\s.+'
```

Also, I have been trying to make it with new concatenations:

```
grep -E '1\s|[A-Z].+'
```

But it doesn't work. `grep` begins to select a similar pattern in different parts of the text:

```sh
awk '{$1=$1}1'   #done already
tr -s "\t\r\n\v" #done already
tr -d "\t\b\r"   #done already
```

How can I grab:

- grab one `newline`
- grab the whole second line after *one* `newline`
- grab the number `$Usd324.34` and remove `Usd`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -En '/^1/ {N;N;s/[[:blank:]]*Usd([^[:blank:]]+)[^\n]*$/\1/; s/\n/ /gp;}' file

1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop 324.32
```

Or this `awk` would also work:

```sh
awk '$0 == 1 {
   printf "%s", $0
   getline
   printf " %s ", $0
   getline
   sub(/Usd/, "")
   print $1
}' file

1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop 324.32
```

Comment: @AlexPixel: Did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec <<EOF
*** *
more text with spaces and  tabs                                                             
*****
1
Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop
    Usd324.32           2 Usd534.22
2
21st New tetx that will like to select with pattern, 334 pop
    Usd162.14

*** *
more text with spaces and tabs, unicode
*****
EOF

while read -r line1; do
  if [[ $line1 =~ ^1$ ]]; then
    read -r line2
    read -r line3col1 dontcare
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$line1" "$line2" "${line3col1#Usd}"
  fi
done
```